# iPhoneの連絡帳やミュージックにあるようなa to z listの実装方法

Tags: react-native

expo
react-native

での実装方法を探しています。
イメージは、連絡帳で五十音順に並んだ個人名があり、画面右側に存在する個人名のあいうえおの見出しがあり、タップで頭出しができるモノです。

APIから動的に取ってきたリストを

```
[
  {
    key: 'あ',
    value: ['あいざわ', 'あだち']
  },
  {
    key: 'い',
    value: ['いしかわ'....
```

とデータを作るのが無難なんでしょうか？

サードパーティのライブラリでもいいですし、世間一般の開発の方がどのように実装するのがスタンダードなのかを知りたいです。